# Disable touch outside UIAlertController frame to cancel

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, uialertcontroller

I have a `UIAlertController` with a style of `ActionSheet`.

I've added a `cancel` action to it.

The thing is that for some reason when the user taps outside of the `ActionSheet` box - the alert is dismissed.

How can I disable this behavior? I want the user to press the cancel button directly.

Comment: I believe if you add a "Cancel" button with `.default` style instead of `.cancel` style, tapping outside the view will *not* dismiss it. The Cancel button won't have a different appearance from any other action buttons though, so that may not be suitable for you.

Comment: @DonMag Yes that's the point. I want it to be visually like a cancel button. So unfortunately, it's not a good solution for me

Comment: Note that with a `.cancel` style button, the completion block will still be called if the user taps outside the view. Which is, I believe, by design according to Apple's HIG

Comment: It’s holds by the system. However you can create your own action sheet instead.

Answer (score 2):

**swift 4 / Xcode 11**

Hi. To disable user interaction (example: tapping anywhere but the cancel button), call the present method in your alert function and set it's completion closure as below code.

```
present(alertController, animated: true) {
   alertController.view.superview?.subviews[0].isUserInteractionEnabled = false
}
```

The whole example:

```
func alertMe() {

let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Tapping Test", message: "User Interaction on the view is disabled", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel) { UIAlertAction in

// do something/call someone/or nothing :)
NSLog("cancel Button is Pressed")

}

alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

present(alertController, animated: true){
            alertController.view.superview?.subviews[0].isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
}
```